# Angular Drop Down 2 way DataBind

Tags: angular

I've got an issue with Angular 6 dropdown data binding...

This is very basic app & this is for my self study.

Its simple.I have separate web api end point to get data & insert data at the moment.

its simple student data.

[image]

& This is my angular view.

[image]

When user click right side student grid Edit.then relevant data load into left side form.don't think about the data.those are for temporary.

[image]

I have a drop down for gender.so when user click right side grid.then gender must loaded in to left side form.
but that part doesn't work.

Left Side Component - StudentRegComponent
Right Side Component - StudentListComponent

I tried to access StudentRegComponent from StudentListComponent and bind dropdown data.that one also doesn't work.i think there is a problem with my approach
I have highlighted some areas using ** please check those places.

How should i approach this?

I ll add part of my code.if you want complete code please let me know.

Student Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';


import { Student } from './student.model';
import { Genre } from './genre';

**const genreList = [
  new Genre(0, 'Male' ),
  new Genre(1, 'Female'),
];**

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class StudentService {
  studentList : Student[];
  selectedStudent : Student;
  selectedgender : Genre;

  constructor(private http : Http) { }


  GetGenreList(): Genre[] {
    return genreList;
 }


  PostStudent(student : Student){
    console.log('Test');
    var body = JSON.stringify(student);
    console.log(body);
    var headerOptions = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({method : RequestMethod.Post,headers : headerOptions});
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:57679/Student/Create',body,requestOptions).map(x => x.json());
  }

  // putEmployee(id, emp) {
  //   var body = JSON.stringify(emp);
  //   var headerOptions = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  //   var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Put, headers: headerOptions });
  //   return this.http.put('http://localhost:28750/api/Employee/' + id,
  //     body,
  //     requestOptions).map(res => res.json());
  // }

  GetStudentList(){

    console.log("get data");
    this.http.get('http://localhost:57679/Student/GetList')
    .map((data : Response) =>{
      return data.json() as Student[];
    }).toPromise().then(x => {
      this.studentList = x;
    })
  }

  UpdateStudent(id, emp) {
    var body = JSON.stringify(emp);
    var headerOptions = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    var requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ method: RequestMethod.Put, headers: headerOptions });
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:57679/Student/Update',
      body,
      requestOptions).map(res => res.json());
  }

  // deleteEmployee(id: number) {
  //   return this.http.delete('http://localhost:28750/api/Employee/' + id).map(res => res.json());
  // }

}
```

StudentRegComponent

```
import { StudentService } from './../shared/student.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Genre } from '../shared/genre';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-reg',
  templateUrl: './student-reg.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-reg.component.css']
})
export class StudentRegComponent implements OnInit {

  **genreList: Genre[];
  selectedgender = 0;

  selectedG : Genre;** 

  constructor(private studentService : StudentService) { }


  ngOnInit() {

    this.genreList = this.studentService.GetGenreList();
    this.resetForm();
  }

  onChange(deviceValue) {
    console.log("nnnn " + deviceValue);
}

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form != null)
      form.reset();
      this.studentService.selectedStudent = {
      Id: null,
      FirstName: '',
      LastName: '',
      ParentName: '',
      FullName : '',
      Gender: this.selectedG,
      DOB: ''
    }
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value.Id == null) {
      this.studentService.PostStudent(form.value)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.resetForm(form);
          this.studentService.GetStudentList();
          //this.toastr.success('New Record Added Succcessfully', 'Employee Register');
        })
    }
    else {
      this.studentService.UpdateStudent(form.value.Id, form.value)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.studentService.GetStudentList();
       // this.toastr.info('Record Updated Successfully!', 'Employee Register');
      });
    }
  }


}
```

StudentListComponent Component

```
// import { StudentRegComponent } from './../student-reg/student-reg.component';
import { Student } from './../shared/student.model';
import { StudentService } from './../shared/student.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentRegComponent } from '../student-reg/student-reg.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-list',
  templateUrl: './student-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-list.component.css']
})
export class StudentListComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private studentService : StudentService) { }

   **saro = new StudentRegComponent(this.studentService);**

  ngOnInit() {
    this.studentService.GetStudentList();
    //this.saro.selectedgender = 1;
    // studentRegComponent : StudentRegComponent;
  }

  showForEdit(std: Student) {

    // this.studentService.selectedgender = std.Gender;   
    this.studentService.selectedStudent = Object.assign({}, std);
    // this.saro.selectedgender = 1;
    // this.saro.selectedgender =  Object.assign({}, 1);
  }



  key: string = 'name'; //set default
  reverse: boolean = false;
  sort(key){
    console.log('sor');
    this.key = key;
    this.reverse = !this.reverse;
  }  
  // onDelete(id: number) {
  //   if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?') == true) {
  //     this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id)
  //     .subscribe(x => {
  //       this.employeeService.getEmployeeList();
  //       this.toastr.warning("Deleted Successfully","Employee Register");
  //     })
  //   }
  // }
}
```

Student Model

```
import { Genre } from './genre';
export class Student {
    Id :number;
    ParentName: string;
    FirstName : string;
    LastName : string;
    FullName : string;
    DOB : string;
    Gender : Genre;

}
```

Genre Model

```
   export class Genre {
        constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {
        }
     }
```

StudentListComponent html

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" [(ngModel)]="filter">      
  </nav>
<table class="table table-sm table-hover">
    <!-- <tr *ngFor="let game of games | orderBy: key : reverse | filter:filter | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i = index"> -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th (click)="sort('FirstName')">FirstName
                <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" *ngIf="key =='FirstName'" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
              </th>
              <th (click)="sort('LastName')">LastName
                  <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" *ngIf="key =='LastName'" [ngClass]="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                </th>

            </tr>
          </thead>

  <tr *ngFor="let student of studentService.studentList | orderBy: key : reverse | filter:filter |  paginate: { itemsPerPage: 5, currentPage: p }; let i = index">

      <td>{{i}}</td>
    <td>{{student.FirstName}}</td>  
    <td>{{student.LastName}}</td>
    <!-- <td>{{student.EmpCode}}</td> -->
    <td>
      <a class="btn text-warning" (click)="showForEdit(student)">
        <i class="">Edit</i>
      </a>
      <a class="btn text-danger" (click)="onDelete(student.Id)">
        <i class="">Delete</i>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

StudentRegComponent html

```
<form class="stdform" #studentForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(studentForm)">
  <input type="hidden" name="Id" #Id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="studentService.selectedStudent.Id">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" name="FirstName" #FirstName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="studentService.selectedStudent.FirstName"
        placeholder="First Name" required>
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="FirstName.invalid && FirstName.touched">This Field is Required.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" name="LastName" #LastName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="studentService.selectedStudent.LastName" placeholder="Last Name"
        required>
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="LastName.invalid && LastName.touched">This Field is Required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" name="ParentName" #ParentName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="studentService.selectedStudent.ParentName" placeholder="ParentName">
  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <input class="form-control" name="DOB" #DOB="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="studentService.selectedStudent.DOB" placeholder="Emp DOB">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-6">

         <select id="gender" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="selectedgender" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"  class="form-control">
          <option *ngFor="let gen of genreList" [value]="gen.id" >
            {{gen.name}}
          </option>
        </select>

       <!-- <select id="gender" name="gender" [(ngModel)]="selectedgender" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"  class="form-control">
          <option *ngFor="let gen of genreList" [value]="gen.id" >
            {{gen.name}}
          </option>
        </select> -->

      </div>



  </div>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
      <button [disabled]="!studentForm.valid" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info">
        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-secondary" (click)="resetForm(studentForm)">
        <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i> Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the select to the **selectedgender**- property ([(ngModel)]="selectedgender") in StudentRegComponent. But this property is never updated.

**[(ngModel)]="studentService.selectedStudent.Gender.id"** in the select tag should do what you want.

Comment: I see that the Gender property in your data is only the number, even though its of type Genre in your model. So try: [(ngModel)]="studentService.selectedStudent.Gender" (without accessing the id of Gender)

Comment: Hi @yannick - yes it's working.Thanks a lot, dude. did another few modifications also. But now my problem is reset & ngOnInit.
Because when this form load, I want to set default dropdown value as Male. When the user selects whatever, when we reset it, then I want to show male as well.
How should I fix that?

Comment: You can set a default in your model like: public Gender: number = 0;
Compare: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mftm4x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yes, It's working now thanks a lot. But in my resetForm function -- 
resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form != null)
      form.reset();
      this.studentService.selectedStudent = {
      Id: null,
      FirstName: '',
      LastName: '',
      ParentName: '',
      FullName : '',
      Gender: this.Gender,
      DOB: ''
    }
  }
When i reset value is blank in drop down.

Comment: Thats probably because this.Gender isn't set. Instead of creating a new object like this you can just call "this.studentService.selectedStudent = new Student();" Like this the default we defined in the model is applied and the dropdown should show up with male.